# How to send keyboard input in real time to server - python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a job that I need to make a tcp connection with socket.  right.  but I need that what the client type is sent to the server.  that is, what is being typed at the client's prompt needs to be appearing at the server's prompt at the same time.  including, if I delete a letter from the phrase or word in the client prompt, the letter also needs to be deleted in real time in the server prompt. (all this without having to press "enter")

How do i do this in python?

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this. This will save my semester from college

Comment: There are various ways you could approach this. SSH's approach to this problem is to send every keypress to the server, including when someone presses the backspace key. Editing the prompt happens on the server. The telnet approach would be to have the client be responsible for letting the user edit the prompt, and only send the prompt to the server when the client presses enter.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to learn about the `getch` module